# Set-Cookie for cross-origin XHR request not setting any cookie in the browser

Tags: cookies, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I have two origins: `example.com` and `api.example.com`.

I have some Javascript code on `example.com` which eventually calls `api.example.com`. The response includes a `Set-Cookie` header, however the cookie is never set (Chrome).

Here is the contents of the Set-Cookie header as observed in the chrome console.

```
session=<redacted>; expires=Mon, 25 Dec 2023 00:10:58 GMT; domain=.example.com; path=/; secure; samesite=none; httponly
```

There is even a "Cookie" tab on the request which shows the parsed out cookie. However, when I navigate to the "Application -> Cookies" tab, I never see the cookie actually get persisted.

My goal is that my XHR request to `api.example.com` should set a cookie that works on both `api.example.com` and `example.com`. I thought the `domain = .example.com` would work with that.

Why is my `Set-Cookie` header response in my XHR request not persisting cookies?